# Insert two data sets into one sql row - Power Automate

Tags: sql, artificial-intelligence, power-automate

I have two Arrays from a PDF Model. I want to combine both into one row in a sql insert but when I tried it I get a double "apply to each" so I get 9 rows instead of three. Have somebody an idea how to fix it? They have both the same Forcast_Time so I want to insert the buy/sell/deviation in the same row and not get them 3 times with different variations. Thanks

[image: Flow]

Comment: Show us the data, will be easier to help. If you have two arrays and you loop over them nested, 3 x 3 = 9. You need to join the arrays or at least preprocess the data so as to create a single dataset.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Nested "apply to each" will inevitably behave as you describe.

Could you possibly insert a new row in the first "apply to each" and update that row in the following one (without having them nested then)?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).